# Changing Theme with Material ui V.5 - Compiling error Importing styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

I need help using material ui custom theme. It get Error in style components.
I have already installed the following:
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled - and continues with same error.
I'm using React 18 and Material V.5 "@mui/material": "^5.6.3"

[My code in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v34lD.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM4g5.png)

My reputation, does not permit do embebed an image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mErje.png)

```js
import Notes from './pages/Notes';
import Bancos from './pages/Bancos';
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@/mui/material/styles';
import { purple } from '@mui/material/colors';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {  
      main: '#fefefe',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: purple
    },
    typography: {
      fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
      fontWeigthLigth: 400,
      fontWeigthRegular: 500,
      fontWeigthMedium: 600,
      fontWeigthBold: 700,
    }
  }
})


class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <themeProvider theme={ theme }>
        <div>
          <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Notes />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/bancos">
                <Bancos />
              </Route>
          </Switch>
         </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
        </themeProvider>
      )
    }
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue shown in your screenshot is caused by a typo in this import:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@/mui/material/styles';
```

You have an extra '/' after '@'.

Note that `createMuiTheme` is deprecated so you'll likely want to use [createTheme](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#createtheme-options-args-theme) instead.

It also looks like you're using MUI v5 in which case, you'll want to import [ThemeProvider](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#themeprovider) from `@mui/material/styles` (MUI v5) instead of `@material-ui/core/styles` (Material-UI v4).

Some other minor issues:

- `palette.secondary.main` doesn't accept color objects
- `fontWeigthLigth` typo
- `<themeProvider>` typo

I suggest installing a linter or other tools that can easily identify issues like this.